# Randomly pressing buttons of a calculator

Tags: expected-value, problem-solving, calculator

There's a normal scientific calculator with only $12$ buttons: from $0$ to $9$ and $+-$

Randomly press these buttons $n$ times. **What will be the math expectation of the result?** (Imagine that the operation "$=$" is automatically executed after you press $n$ buttons)

For example, when $n=0$, $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$; when $n=1$, $\mathbb{E}(X)=\cfrac{\left(\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{9} i\right) + 2\times 0}{10 + 2}=\cfrac{45}{12}=\cfrac{15}{4}$

Expressions that are not allowed (wrong expressions) should be counted $0$. Most of the wrong expressions are due to syntax error.

The following is some criteria you can refer to (if you are not familiar with calculator) but not exact specification.

**Update**

The following is the part of results solved by python.

This is the calculator with only $0$ to $9$, $+$ and $-$

[image: calculator with only 0~9+-]

The code is here:

```
from itertools import product
tar = list(range(10)) + ['+', '-'] #operator

class Stack(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def last(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)

op = ('+', '-', '*', '/')
for i in range(5):
    n = i + 1
    cnt = 0
    per = product(tar, repeat=n) # product
    for tup in per:
        list1 = list(tup)
        
        # convert digits into numbers
        pos = 0
        list2 = []
        while pos < len(list1):
            if type(list1[pos]) == int:
                num = 0
                while pos < len(list1) and type(list1[pos]) == int:
                    num *= 10
                    num += list1[pos]
                    pos += 1
                list2.append(num)
            else:
                list2.append(list1[pos])
                pos += 1

        # exclude expressions that are not allowed
        #if(list2[0] in ('*', '/')):
            #continue
        if(list2[-1] in op):
            continue
        flag = 0
        for k in range(len(list2)):
            if(k != len(list2) - 1):
                if(list2[k] in op and list2[k + 1] in op):
                    flag = 1
                if(list2[k] == '/' and list2[k + 1] == 0):
                    flag = 1
        if flag:
            continue

        # First digit processing
        if(len(list2) > 1 and list2[0] == '+'):
            list2 = list2[1:]
        if(len(list2) > 1 and list2[0] == '-'):
            list2[1] *= -1
            list2 = list2[1:]

        # Prefix Expression
        res = []
        s = Stack()
        optPriorityDict = {'+': 1, '-': 1, '*': 2, '/': 2}
        for ele in list2[::-1]:
            if type(ele) == int:
                res.insert(0, ele)
            elif ele in op:
                while(not s.isEmpty() and optPriorityDict[s.last()] >= optPriorityDict[ele]):
                    res.insert(0, s.pop())
                s.push(ele)
        while not s.isEmpty():
            res.insert(0, s.pop())

        def evalPreExp(preExpList):
            s = Stack()
            for ele in preExpList[::-1]:
                if type(ele) == int:
                    s.push(ele)
                else:
                    op1 = s.pop()
                    op2 = s.pop()
                    try:
                         out = toMath(ele, op1, op2)
                    except:
                         return 0
                    s.push(out)
            return s.pop()
         
        def toMath(op, op1, op2):
            if op == '+':
                 return op1 + op2
            elif op == '-':
                 return op1 - op2
            elif op == '*':
                 return op1 * op2
            elif op == '/':
                 return op1 / op2

        cnt += evalPreExp(res)
    print("When n =", n, ", E(X)=", cnt, '/', len(tar) ** n)
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144664/discussion-on-question-by-sundayli-randomly-pressing-buttons-of-a-calculator); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.